# Automatically insert whitespace in RStudio script

Tags: r, rstudio, whitespace, shortcut

In the same ways that lines can be correctly indented using `Ctrl + I` or `Cmd + I`, is there a shortcut to automatically insert correct whitespace in RStudio scripts?

For example, for this:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(3,4,5,6,7))
```

RStudio gives information saying *"expected whitespace around '<-' operator"* and *"expected whitespace around '=' operator"*. Is there a shortcut to get this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

Comment: One solution would be to use the `styler` package. Will not style on the fly but ...

Comment: Install styler and it automatically adds an addin to the list of addins for you in Rstudio. Then click `style active file` from the dropdown menu in the addins. You can bind this option to custom keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under RStudio you can select the code and type `Ctrl+Shift+a` in Windows & Linux or `Cmd+Shift+a` for macOS to trigger code reformatting, see [RStudio shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts).

Result:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

Comment: Thanks @Waldi! For Mac this is `Cmd+Shift+A`.

Comment: This solution is even listed [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) where I was originally looking, but just searching for the wrong thing

Comment: Thanks for the link, I put it in the answer for further reference